# How to get text from textFieldDidEndEditing?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Probably a simple answer to this,

How can i pass the `textField.text` from an UIAlertView that has a textfield in it

to a `-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`

i tried to create a property NSString and make it equal to `textField.text` and tried to `NSLog` it and it came back `NULL`

Comment: I'd recommend posting the code where you have create the `NSString` property and attempt to save the text field's text to it. This should be fairly trivial.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *string;
in the .m file under the interface

Comment: Have you set the delegate of the UITextField?

Comment: Yes as UITextFieldDelegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Updated Answer

To retrieve the text of a text field in the `UIAlertView` you can use the [`textFieldAtIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/textFieldAtIndex:) method. You don't need to involve the text field delegate at all.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0]; // adjust the index if you have more than one text field.

    NSLog(@"Text: %@", textField.text);
}
```

## Original Answer

<strike>You have a couple of options here.</strike>

## Option 1

Store a reference to the text field as a property, it seems likely you are already doing this.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
```

This can then be accessed directly from the `UIAlertView` delegate method, assuming the delegate is the same object that has the reference to the text field:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"Text: %@", self.textField.text);
}
```

## Option 2

If for some reason you don't have a reference to your text field you can get it from the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` delegate method, firstly create a property to store the text:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *textFieldText;
```

Then update that when the text field delegate method is called.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.textFieldText = textField.text; 
}
```

Then you can access this property in the `UIAlertView` delegate method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"Text: %@", self.textFieldText);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, this TextField is actually a uialertview with a textfield in it

Comment: i tried the second option and didnt work, comes back as null

Comment: That is a crucial bit of the puzzle, I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @farhan answer updated. I would highly recommend updating your question to include the fact that the text field is a part of the `UIAlertView` as this is significantly different to a standalone text field.

Comment: okay thanks alot it worked for me, and i will change my question.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working for me:

```
UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Do you want to call?"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField * alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
alertTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
[alertTextField setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[alert show];
```

and delegates:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if (buttonIndex==1) {
    return;
}
UITextField *title1;// = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

title1= [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
NSString *messageStr = title1.text;

if ([messageStr isEqualToString:@""]) {
    return;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just declare NSString object in 
    @interface LoginDialogVC ()
    {
        NSString strText;
    }
    @end

```
@implementation LoginDialogVC
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    strText = textField.text;
}
```

after that use strText whenever you want to use.